# c++ QT default style too bright

Tags: c++, qt

Since i moved to window 8 and QT 5 ( i had vista before ), every application i'm writting have a too bright style. Border of widgets are nearly hidden.

I already tried :

```
QApplication::setStyle( "windowsvista" );
```

but it didn't work. Is there a better solution than change every colors with style sheets?

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot for your application and a good-looking application on your system?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qstylefactory.html#keys - check it on your OS

Answer (score 0):

For Window 7 and Qt 5, `QStyleFactory::keys()` just support four styles:

```
Windows
WindowsXP
WindowsVista
Fusion
```

I have two ways to change that, if you didn't like them.

1. Implement a class what inherit `QStyle`, then call `setStyle` of `QApplication`.
2. Use the `setStyleSheet` of `QMainWindow` in `Qt Designer` or C++ project.